# Dynamic Get String Function

Tags: c, stdin

Platform: Windows Vista Home Premium SP2 x86

Compiler: MinGW (GCC 4.7.1 tdm-1) (IDE: Code::Blocks)

I am writing a function that uses the fairly common trash collector loop while(getc(stdin) != '\n') to write a dynamic get string function that will read any data left in standard input by a fgets() call. I am writing the function on windows because I do not have access to my computer currently, just to let you guys know. But my problem is I want my function dgets() to malloc() a buffer if the pointer given to it is NULL but at the same time I want the function to return an integer. So my solution to this problem is a pointer to a char pointer. The function would be called like so.

```
char *s = NULL;
int n = 0;

if(dgets(&s, &n) != 0) //ERROR
```

I do not use pointers to pointers very often so I was a bit confused when my function crashed. I narrowed down the problem to how I was dereferencing 's', by using the following the loop.

```
char* *s;
int i = 0;

*s = malloc(32);

for(; i < 32; i++) printf("*s[%i] == %c\n", i, *s[i]);
```

When the above code is compiled and run it crashes. My question is why? and here is the function for context. P.S. it has not be tested yet but any comments would be appreciated.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int dgets(char* *s, size_t *n)
{
    if(n == NULL) return 1;
    if(*n < 0) return 1;
    if(*n == 0) *n = 32;

    if(s == NULL) return 1;
    if(*s == NULL && (*s = malloc(*n)) == NULL) return 1;

    int i = 0;

    for(; i <= *n; i++) *s[i] = 0;

    if(fgets(*s, *n, stdin) == NULL) return 1;

    //Since fgets() will put newlines in the buffer, input is line buffered,
    //and the buffer was initilized to zero if the last element
    //is a nonzero value and not a newline then there must be a newline left
    //in stdin.
    if(*s[*n - 1] != 0 && *s[*n - 1] != '\n')
    {
        i = *n;
        int byte = 0;

        char *tmp = NULL;

        for(; (byte = getc(stdin)) != '\n'; i++)
        {
            if(byte == EOF) return 1;

            if(i == *n)
            {
                //eventually an arbitrary limit will be put here to limit the
                //size of the buffer
                *n *= 2;

                if((tmp = realloc(*s, *n)) == NULL) return 1;

                *s = tmp;
            }

            *s[i] = (char)byte;
        }

        //reallocates the buffer so that it is exact size
        if(*n != i + 2 && (tmp = realloc(*s, i + 2)) == NULL) return 1;

        *s = tmp;
        *n = i + 2;

        *s[i] = (char)byte;
        *s[i + 1] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two problems I noticed .

1. type mismatch

   ```
   int n;
   if(dgets(&s, &n) != 0)
   ```

   **dgets** prototype is **int dgets(char **s, size_t *n)**

   &n : **int ***, but require **size_t ***
2. Out-of-range array access & dereference error

   ```
   for(; i <= *n; i++) *s[i] = 0;
   ```

   It has access to the external memory that is reserved.

   It should be **i < *n** and **(*s)[i] = 0;**

   `*s[i]` meant `*(s[i])`

**It is also necessary to change the remainder of the program in accordance with the above change.**

Comment: `0` means  false(failure) in the C language.
So,
`return 0` as the value when an error has occurred , it can be suitable.
If you `return 1` ,
 It is preferable to replacement such as  `return DGETS_FAILUER`.

Comment: In order to avoid confusion
It write as `char *p = *s;`...`p[i]` instead of `(*s)[i]`.